には vs にとって vs のため
I already understood the difference between にとって　and のため:
私にとって　to me (or ’for me’); in my perception, or weighed against my skills/needs
私のため　－　’for me’ as in "for my good
But what about には? I find it interchangeable with にとって in some cases, such as
私にとって難しい and この本は子供には難しすぎるだろう. So, 1) Am I right that these are the same thing?　2) I understand correctly that there are cases when に は cannot be replaced with something, for example, 今後のあなたの研究には　何が必要ですか？ It seems to be a common value "for", without an accent　"in someone's perception"（にとって） or  "for me" as in "for my good" (のため)

This is the most exhaustive list of Japanese particles I know of: Japanese particles - Wikipedia.
According to this list, there are 3 meanings in the には particle:

Nouns: "for"; this is what you've described more extensively as: to me (or ’for me’); in my perception, or weighed against my skills/needs; this is interchangeable with にとって.
example: 七味は、私には辛すぎる。 | 七味は、私にとって（は）辛すぎる。

Verb: "in order to"; this is what you described as "for my good", and can also mean "to be able to (do something)", "in order to (do something)"; this is interchangeable with ためには (only precede with の if preceded by a noun/pronoun).
example: いい大学に受かるためには真剣に勉強にないといけません。　|　いい大学に受かるには真剣に勉強にないといけません

Noun: "in, to"; this is not interchangeable like the two above.
example: 家の前にはアサガオを植えましょう。



ty for answer, its useful for me!
I'll ask you something else, if you don't mind.
UNGRAMMATICAL: この仕事は私にとってできない
GRAMMATICAL: この仕事は私にはできない
The meaning seems to be clear, but it seems not. Can you help me if it's not too much trouble? we just can't put verbs after にとって?

@DmitriiHude にとって is used to compare something to your perceptions/needs/skills; in that sense, it is much like the "than" in English and it requires an adjective to work, so yes, no verbs after it. には is OK in this case because に marks the passive agent and は marks the topic.
